# js for loop keeps looping unlimitedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, summernote

I really stuck on this part. firstly, I successfully collected all img sources from summernote editor which user uploads. but when I try to loop them to check if img links encoded to base64 and try to decode them and save them together. but here in my code fo loop keeps looping unlimitedly. Is there some problem with the looping list of img tags?

```
function getAllImages() {
let images = $(".note-editable p").find('img').map(function() {
      return $(this).attr('src')
    }).get();
console.logt(images);
 let base64regex = /^([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{4})*(([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{2}==)|([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{3}=))?$/;
 let imgSrc = [];
   for(let i=0; images.length; i++){
     if(base64regex.test(images[i])) {
        console.log("["+images[i]+"]");
        let decoded=atob(images[i]);
        console.log("img decoded");
        imgSrc.push(decoded);
     } 
     else if(base64regex.test(images[i]) == false){

        console.log("["+images[i]+"]");
        imgSrc.push(images[i]);
     }      
 }
  return imgSrc;
 }
```

Comment: `for(let i=0; images.length; i++){` should be `for(let i=0; i < images.length; i++){`

Comment: `for(let i=0; images.length; i++){`  you're missing a terminal condition, it should be `i < images.length`

Comment: ah thanks a lot, I spent my whole day for this. Interesting why js did not show any error there?

Comment: @AzizSirojiddinov - Because there's no error. The test expression in a `for` loop is just an expression. `images.length` is an expression. :-) `for` doesn't requires that the expression evaluate to `true` or `false` specifically (which is someimtes quite useful). The expression's result is then tested to see if it's truthy (= the loop should continue) or falsy (it shouldn't). If `images.length` is a number that isn't 0, it's truthy, so it'll continue forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `i < images.length` in the for loop.

```js
function getAllImages() {
let images = $(".note-editable p").find('img').map(function() {
      return $(this).attr('src')
    }).get();
console.logt(images);
 let base64regex = /^([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{4})*(([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{2}==)|([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{3}=))?$/;
 let imgSrc = [];
   for(let i=0; i < images.length; i++){
     if(base64regex.test(images[i])) {
        console.log("["+images[i]+"]");
        let decoded=atob(images[i]);
        console.log("img decoded");
        imgSrc.push(decoded);
     } 
     else if(base64regex.test(images[i]) == false){

        console.log("["+images[i]+"]");
        imgSrc.push(images[i]);
     }      
 }
  return imgSrc;
 }
```